# In SQL Server 2005 is there any way to change the collation of a whole database at once?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, collation

Using SQL Server Management Studio, I have backed up a database from one server and restored it to my local copy of SQL Server 2005. But the collation of the backed up database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI and I am attempting to compare columns to a database which is Latin1_General_CI_AI.

The database has a lot of keys and constraints which makes changing each column individually throw errors.

What is the best way to change the collation of a whole database in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple way, you must change collation of Db (`ALTER DATABASE`), and all columns individually (`ALTER TABLE`). Maybe there is a ready to use tools, maybe you need to write it youself. Maybe Data Comparison Tool of Visual Studio 2010 can be useful (`Data -> Data Compare` menu).

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE` does not change the collation of the columns in any existing user-defined tables.

Comment: If your columns use the database default (which I would always recommend anyway) then there's no need to change those individually...

Comment: @marc_s oh, I see. Well, then maybe setting db collation would be enough.

Comment: @marc_s: are you sure that such 'database default' collated columns will magically change their collation, recreate their indexes an so on? I somehow don't believe - but I've no first-hand experience either.

Comment: @Arvo: I believe they'll adapt to a changing collation, but indices is a different story....

Answer (score 0):

You can change the collation of any new objects that are created in a user database by using the `COLLATE` clause of the [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269.aspx) statement. **This statement does not change the collation of the columns in any existing user-defined tables.** These can be changed by using the `COLLATE` clause of [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

---

Refer to:

[Setting and Changing the Database Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx)

[Setting and Changing the Column Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx)